# spyder MySqldb module has no attribute 'connection'

Tags: python, mysql, spyder

I am pretty new with Python. I installed anaconda from continuum and MySQLdb from Pypi. I am struggling to run this code in spyder.

```
import MySQLdb 

class db_class:
    def __init__(self,db):
        self.Mdb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='',
            db=db)

        self.Mcursor = self.Mdb.cursor()

    def __del__self(self):
        self.Mcursor.close()
        self.Mdb.close()

    def execute(self,Aquery):
        return self.Mcursor.execute(Aquery)

    def fetchall(self):
        return self.Mcursor.fetchall()

    def fetchone(self):
        return self.Mcursor.fetchone()

    def description(self):
        return self.Mcursor.description


if __name__=="__main__":
    db=db_class('XXX')
```

I am getting this in the ipython console:

```
File "C:/Users/...", line 12, in __init__
  self.Mdb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'.
```

MySQL has been installed in the following path
`C:\Users\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I solved my issue thanks to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/. Installed directly the connector from there in anaconda prompt using  
conda install mysql_connector_python.